# Hazecast-Kubernetes Springboot application embedded cluster warning

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast, spring-cache

i have deploy embedded hazelcast cluster on kubernetes, i am getting below warning. disabled auto increment flag and portCount still getting error.

Config :

```
Config config = new Config();
config.setClusterName("cache-cluster");
JoinConfig joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true)
            .setProperty("namespace", "<Namespace>")
            .setProperty("service-name", "<Service-name>");
```

i have opened container port in kubernetes. services are able to create the cluster but getting the below warning continuously.

```
2020-10-29 14:04:40.092  WARN  [hz.silly_lalande.IO.thread-in-1    ]  c.h.i.n.t.TcpIpConnection                    - [22.249.47.234]:5701 [cache-cluster] [4.0.1] Connection[id=2, /22.249.47.234:5701->/22.249.5.1:52152, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=2, /22.249.47.234:5701->/22.249.5.1:52152, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE], thread=hz.silly_lalande.IO.thread-in-1 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: ?
    at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:116)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioPipeline.lambda$start$0(NioPipeline.java:127)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processTaskQueue(NioThread.java:354)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:289)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:248)
2020-10-29 14:13:10.038  WARN  [hz.silly_lalande.IO.thread-in-2    ]  c.h.i.n.t.TcpIpConnection                    - [22.249.47.234]:5701 [cache-cluster] [4.0.1] Connection[id=3, /22.249.47.234:5701->/22.249.55.1:52730, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=3, /22.249.47.234:5701->/22.249.55.1:52730, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE], thread=hz.silly_lalande.IO.thread-in-2 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TLS handshake header detected, but plain protocol header was expected.
    at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.loadProtocol(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:134)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:90)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:382)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:367)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:293)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:248)
2020-10-29 14:13:10.039  WARN  [hz.silly_lalande.IO.thread-in-0    ]  c.h.i.n.t.TcpIpConnection                    - [22.249.47.234]:5701 [cache-cluster] [4.0.1] Connection[id=4, /22.249.47.234:5701->/22.249.55.1:52736, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=4, /22.249.47.234:5701->/22.249.55.1:52736, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE], thread=hz.silly_lalande.IO.thread-in-0 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TLS handshake header detected, but plain protocol header was expected.
    at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.loadProtocol(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:134)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:90)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:382)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:367)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:293)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:248)
```

Not sure why connection is happing here

```
[22.249.47.234]:5701 [cache-cluster] [4.0.1] Connection[id=4, **/22.249.47.234:5701->/22.249.55.1:52736**, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=4, **/22.249.47.234:5701->/22.249.55.1:52736**, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE], thread=hz.silly_lalande.IO.thread-in-0
```

is there any configuration missing?

Comment: 1. What Hazelcast version do you use? 2. Do you use `hazelcast-all` dependency or `hazelcast` and `hazelcast-kubernetes` dependencies?

Comment: I'm using `hazelcast` 4.0.1 version and `hazelcast-kubernetes`.

Comment: What version of `hazelcast-kubernetes`?

Comment: `hazelcast-kubernetes` version 2.0.1 and also I'm using `hazelcast-spring` version 4.0.1

Comment: The configuration and versions look fine. Could you check if the following guide works for you? https://guides.hazelcast.org/hazelcast-embedded-springboot/

Comment: So with above configuration I'm able to Store data and retrieve from the cache object. But I'm getting that warning. Additionally I updated the kubernetes service object by removing `type: LoadBalancer` field and created service. It solved the problem and I'm not getting the warning. So is it related to loadbalancer service of kubernetes which exposes external ports?

Comment: @MAYUR KUMBHAR What is your infrastructure? If you service is type LoadBalancer and you're on on-premise cluster like kubeadm or minikube you won't get an external-IP. If you're on cloud and you create a LoadBalancer service the cloud provider integration will take care of creating the needed cloud resources, and writing back the endpoint where your service will be available. If you don’t have a cloud provider integration or a controller for this purpose, your Service resource will remain in Pending state.

Comment: It's on-premise cluster with Kubeadm. I'll verify again with configuration for service component.

Comment: Hi @MAYURKUMBHAR so if you changed it from LoadBalancer to ClusterIP it works?  If you have type LoadBalancer on your on-premise cluster with kubeadm you won't get an external-ip, and your Service resource will remain in Pending state. You would have to use tool like [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to use LoadBalancer type or service in your on-premise cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/issues/186
Adding **containerPort: 5701** to your HZ service manifest should work.

It should work irrespective of the type of service whether it is LoadBalancer or ClusterIP

Can you confirm clustering is working fine too even in the case of warnings?